# Windows 8 App Development - Override Home Button

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, tablet

Is there a way to bind an event to the "home button" press for devices with a hardware button like the Microsoft Surface?

The app is not intended to be published in the store and I have **full control over the devices** as they are intended to be used internally for the sales team of a company.

Whatever internal Windows manipulation needs to be done in order to be able to override the Home Button would be possible to do for our setup.